# What does the notation $\circ$ mean?

Tags: notation

I can't search it on google, because it doesn't support symbols like these.

It might have to do with binary operations, I think.

Comment: Without some context, it could mean almost anything.  Often $f\circ g$ means the function or operation that results from performing the operation $g$ followed by the operation $f$.

Comment: Please tell us where you are encountering this symbol.

Comment: As an expoent it means "degree": $45{{}^\circ}=\pi /4$.

Comment: It also means "connected component containing the identity".

Answer (score 10):

Since you mention "binary operation", I'll point out some of the more common meanings of $\circ$ when speaking of functions and/or binary operations.

The symbol "$\circ$" denotes the [composition of functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), [composition of relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_composition), or the composition of permutations, and more generally, denotes a binary operation, sometimes described as a *law of composition*, where $f\circ g$ is the function or operation resulting from performing the function/operation $g$, followed by the function/operation of $f$.

When denoting function composition, for example, if we are given that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions of $x \in \mathbb R$ such that: $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\; g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then $\;f\circ g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can be expressed as $$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$$

Comment: Mohamed: does this help? You can accept an answer, even to a question that's on hold. You can also comment, or ask for clarification: I'm here if you need me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually composition of functions as stated in the other answer, but also can mean Hadamard/Schur/entrywise matrix product.